# Как программно открыть Prefab For Editing (режим в котором редактируется Prefab)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, prefabs

Как программно открыть Prefab For Editing (режим в котором редактируется Prefab)?
Нашёл в коде Unity строки которые отвечают за открытия Prefab Mode edit:

```
    string prefabPath = "TerrainTools/StampToolExtended/Terrain(Clone).prefab";
    prefabPath = Application.dataPath+"/"+prefabPath;
    string scenePath = "TerrainTools/StampToolExtended/sceneTerrain.unity";
    scenePath = Application.dataPath+"/"+scenePath;
    try
    {

        Scene scene = EditorSceneManager.NewPreviewScene();
        PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContentsIntoPreviewScene(prefabPath, scene);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log("prefabPath"+prefabPath+" scenePath="+scenePath);
        Debug.LogError(string.Format("Loading Prefab failed: {0}", e.Message));
        return ;
    }
```

Но код выполняется и нечего не происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл [ссылку](https://pastebin.com/GtJeeN3F). И у меня получилось сделать. Код продублирую:

```
public  void OpenPrefabForEditing(UnityEngine.Object prefab)
{
    Type t = typeof(UnityEditor.Experimental.SceneManagement.PrefabStageUtility);
    MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Single(
        m =>
            m.Name == "OpenPrefab"
            && m.GetParameters().Length == 1
            && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(string)
    );
    mi.Invoke(null, new object[] {AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(prefab)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot(gameObject));
```

Comment: Старайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы